# Android phone doesn't recognize Arduino board

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, galaxy

I have a [Samsung Galaxy Gio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Gio) and want to connect it to an [Arduino Leonardo](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLeonardo). I use the [Stackable Bluetooth Shield 2.1](http://store.iteadstudio.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=307) from ITead Studio.

It works with a Windows PC (I can send and receive strings with [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY)), but my phone doesn't even recognize it - the [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) device list is empty.

The strange thing is that a [Galaxy S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S) recognizes the Arduino immediately. And my phone can see all other Bluetooth devices - except the Arduino.

Why can't my Gio recognize the board, when all other devices work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found the problem!

Apparently the Galaxy Gio with Android v2.3.6 has some problems with "special" Bluetooth devices - like Arduino boards.
I installed [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) (I think it's Version 7.1 or 7.2) on the phone and after that it had no problems recognizing the board. That's because CyanogenMod contains many fixes for Bluetooth and other problems.

Now I'm using [ITEAD BT Debugging Assistant](http://blog.iteadstudio.com/make-arduino-talk-with-android-by-bluetooth/) to send and receive strings from/to my board.